# How to pass jsf bean value to css calc function?

Tags: css, jsf, el

I am using ternary operator in style class. I am not able to pass bean value to set width of a table.

Here is my code:

```
<table style="#{manageBean.taskDetail.effort1 &lt; manageBean.taskDetail.effort2 ? 'width:calc((manageBean.taskDetail.effort1/manageBean.taskDetail.effort2)*100%);background-color:blue;' : 'width:10%;background-color:red;'}">
```

If the condition satisfies then width should be displayed based on the calculation. Above calculation is not working.

Any help?

Comment: not question-related but still useful: EL supports `lt`, `le`, `gt`, ... to compare numbers, no need for HTML entities like `&lt;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation is not working because you are nesting an EL expression and this is not possible on JSF 2.2. So, `calc` (css) is taken `manageBean.taskDetail.effort1` literally, in other words, like a string.
You can do this calculation on JS or build a Bean method which calcules the css style. An example:

**View**

```
<table style="#{dummyController.style}">
    <!-- content -->
</table>
```

**Bean**

```
public String getStyle() {
    return number1 > number2? "width:calc((" + (number1 / number2) + ")*100%);background-color:blue;" : "width:10%;background-color:red;";
}
```